# How to write a predicate that means "There is exactly one student in at most one class".

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

This was a question in my discrete math 1 exam but I don't quite remember my answer and everyone seems to disagree with each other so I thought I'd ask what the correct answer is.

Let $C(x,y)$ mean "student $x$ is in class $y$".

Comment: As a note: "The correct answer" doesn't exist, since there are several equivalent predicates which will have the same meaning as the desired statement (this may be the cause of some of the disagreement amongst your peers).

Comment: What do you think the answer is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence as written is ambiguous. It could mean, "There is exactly one student, and she is in at most one class," or it could mean, "There is at most one class satisfying the condition that there is exactly one student in the class." Those are logically distinct sentences. (This might explain why everyone seems to disagree with each other on how to write the predicate.)

Let $Sx$ be  "$x$ is a student," $Kx$ be "$x$ is a class," and $Cxy$ as  you mentioned.

To help, we will review the following phrases:

"There are zero students" -- $\neg(\exists x)(Sx)$

"There is exactly one student" -- $(\exists x)(Sx \wedge (\forall y)(Sy \implies y = x))$

"There is at most one student" -- "There are zero students" $\vee$ "There is exactly one student" -- $\neg(\exists x)(Sx) \vee (\exists x)(Sx \wedge (\forall y)(Sy \implies y = x))$

Okay, using those as references for the number parts, let's try the two interpretations I gave above.

"There is exactly one student, and she is in at most one class."

$(\exists x)(Sx \wedge (\forall y)(Sy \implies y = x) \wedge 
(\neg(\exists y)(Ky \wedge Cxy)\vee (\exists y)((Ky \wedge Cxy) \wedge (\forall z)((Kz \wedge Cxz) \implies z = y)))$

"There is at most one class satisfying the condition that there is exactly one student in the class."

$\neg(\exists x)(Kx \wedge (\exists y)((Sy \wedge Cyx) \wedge (\forall z)((Sz\wedge Czx) \implies z = y))) \vee (\exists x)(Kx \wedge (\exists y)((Sy \wedge Cyx) \wedge (\forall z)((Sz\wedge Czx) \implies z = y)) \wedge (\forall w)(Kw \wedge (\exists y)((Sy \wedge Cyw) \wedge (\forall z)((Sz\wedge Czw) \implies z = y)) \implies w=x))$

Comment: The interpretation I would expect could be stated as "the cardinality of the set of students that attend zero or one class is one". In other words, "with one exception, every student attends at least two classes".

Comment: @DerekElkins Maybe. Eyad H. is best equipped to answer, since he saw the quesiton in original context.

Comment: @Y.Forman There was no context, the entire question was exactly a sentence and a half which I wrote exactly in my question here.

Comment: @EyadH. So... what did you take it to mean? One of the things I said? What Derek said? Or something else?

Comment: @EyadH. Not that this helps you or is in your control, but these sorts of exercises are exactly the sort of exercises that I think are a waste of time when learning about formal logic.

Comment: I vaguely used the second interpretation and wrote some big predicate (two conjuncted predicates), the first one for the "at most one student" part and the second one was for the "in exactly one class" part, since I left that question to the end of the exam and was too tired/run out of time to actually think well enough or even polish the ugly predicate I came up with as time was running out. (which is partly why I can't remember the answer I wrote)

Comment: By second interpretation I meant @Y.Forman 's second interpretation. I hadn't even thought of Derek's interpretation until now

Comment: @Y.Forman would you be able to write the predicates for both interpretations, however? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @EyadH. Edited.

Comment: @Y.Forman I think I remember part of what I wrote now. The part about the first half of at most one student in the same class was, I think, $\forall x \forall y \forall z [ C(x,y) \land C(z,y) \implies (x = z)]$. Is this true? If there are no student then this is vacuously true, but if there are any student then they are just one. I still don't remember the second part.

Comment: @EyadH. The question talks about exactly one student, not at most one student.

Comment: Damn me to hell then lol. Thanks anyways.